# Can an Australian dad + children live in Canada for a year?

Tags: visas, canada

## Dream

My oldest son currently has some (smallish) mental health life-challenges. As part of my parenting, I wish to help with this by living overseas for a year with him. He loves the snow and we're both Australian born with only AU passports, so we thought Canada might be a similar place (read: not *too* challenging like languages, etc) to settle for a year. The idea is like a 'gap' year between primary school and high-school but he will need to go to school there, still. Possibly bring my 2nd and 3rd child also and wifey (pending her work arrangements, else leave her home for a year and please refrain from making jokes about this, etc).

## Goals

- Spend a year away overseas with family (dad (me), 1 child (currently 9) and possibly wife + 2 younger children.
- Child/children go to school.
- I work remotely (i.e. keep current Australian job, just work remotely at destination country [requires internet connection of course]).
- Must have snow + skiing facilities.

## Questions

- Are Australian citizens allowed to live in Canada for 1 year? Is it hard to get the appropriate visas etc?
- I wish to keep my existing AU job (i.e. all salary goes into my AU bank account, I keep paying AU tax) but I will be physically doing my work in the country. This means I won't be stealing a Canadian job from a local.
- Can my child or children go to a school over there?
- Finally (thinking out of the box...) are there any well-known house-swap facilities (e.g. we live in someone's house, they live in ours). Trying to keep costs down.

## FAQ

- Q: Why Canada?
  A: Australia and Canada are [part of some Commonwealth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_of_Nations). So I thought this would be easier than other countries. I have family friends who live at Lake Tahoe, USA (which is my first preference) but you know... USA + visa == ru-roh.
- Q: Do you have to go to Canada?
  A: Nope - open to other options based on visa requirements + ticking off goals listed, above.
- Q: Do you have to remotely work the entire time?
  A: Nope. I have a lot of long service + annual leave owing so I could (probably would) take 4 or 5 months paid leave, if this helps with visa and rules, etc.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for the expats site. All this has much more in common with immigration than travel (school, work, etc) so there is more expertise on the topic there. Plus, try to break it down, there may be more people being able to answer part of your question(s) than all of it.

Comment: Definitely a better fit for expats, but unfortunately I suspect the answer is going to be "no chance".  If you want to try and get a job in Canada it might be possible, but without...  (And certainly the US is NOT an option based on your requirements)

Comment: @Doc please re-read. I do NOT want to get a job. I have a job in AU already. This is the part I do not understand .. when this is not travel any more and .. something else (another stack exchange site?)

Comment: @Pure.Krome the differentiation between travel and expats is time in country and the visas required.  You will essentially be living in Canada, which is a different skill set for the legal peeps active on here than simply visiting.

Comment: Then can this get migrated to that other site, then? cc @ mods

Comment: @Pure.Krome I did read it.  As surprising as it may sound, it's easier to do something like this if you DO get a job in the destination country than if you don't. Work visas to both the US and CA are very possible (even easy, depending on the circumstances).  Year-long "tourist" visas generally are not.

Comment: Ta @Doc - interesting bit of info. I really don't want to leave my current job so i'll leave that as a last resort option ...

Comment: NZ has skiing and would be way easier

Comment: We've been to NZ a few times, so it doesn't feel as 'foreign' or 'remote' to us. That said, totally agreed :) Easier, cheaper, closer, ticks most boxes :)

Answer (score 3):

> Are Australian citizens allowed to live in Canada for 1 year? Is it hard to get the appropriate visa's etc?

Australians fall under Canadas [eTA (Electronic Travel Authorisation)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta.asp) program, which would grant you up to 6 months stay as a visitor (the eTA could be limited to less time than that).

To stay longer than that, you would need to apply for a [temporary resident visitor visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp), which you can do in-country during your initial stay.

> I wish to keep my existing AU job (i.e. all salary goes into my AU bank account, I keep paying AU tax) but I will be physically doing my work in the country. This means I won't be stealing a Canadian job from a local.

This is [acceptable to Canadian immigration](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/work/about.asp):

> **What kind of activities are not considered to be “work”?**
>
> An activity which does not really 'take away' from opportunities for Canadians or permanent residents to gain employment or experience in the workplace is not “work” for the purposes of the definition.
>   Examples of activities for which a person would not normally be remunerated or which would not compete directly with Canadian citizens or permanent residents in the Canadian labour market and which would normally be part-time or incidental to the reason that the person is in Canada include, but are not limited to:
>
> ...
>
> long distance (by telephone or Internet) work done by a temporary resident whose employer is outside Canada and who is remunerated from outside Canada;

You should be fine working for an Australian company while in Canada on a non-work visa.

> Can my child or children go to a school over there?

As you would be a temporary resident (under an eTA or a Temporary Resident Visitor visa) your child [may need a study visa of their own to study in Canada:](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/students/minor.asp)

> It should be noted that minor children of a temporary resident (visitor) who is not authorized to work or study require a study permit to study in Canada.

However, this is contradicted further down that same page:

> If the parent in Canada has valid temporary resident status as a visitor and is authorized to work or study without a permit as per the IRPR, their accompanying minor child in Canada is authorized to study without a study permit at the pre-school, primary or secondary level as per subsection A30(2)

Get a lawyers interpretation of that!

Comment: No contradiction. Father is not authorized to work! Remote is not work.

Comment: Not sure if this should be another question or just an elaboration on the current question but ... is it "hard" to get a Study permit for child/children?